# Get X Y value from Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make this dataframe spit out the "x" value and "y" value and I'm completely stuck. I'm not sure how to go about this and the end goal is to make it plot the X and Y values on a graph, I'm just not sure how I would go about extracting these values. When I do iloc to try and get this information I get the indexes and while this isn't necessarily a problem it just added to my overall confusion. Here's one of my files and either a solution or explanation on how to do it would be extremely appreciated, I keep confusing myself more and more. Thanks so much

EDIT: I got better clarification and realize in this example month would be the x and average would be the y. So I know I can do data.iloc to get these values one by one, but is there a way I could add this to like a for loop for example to iterate through all the values one by one and then have them all get plotted on a graph? I cant think of the best way to accomplish this

```
from flask import render_template, request, redirect
from app import app
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    data = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.files:
            uploaded_file = request.files['filename']
            filepath = os.path.join(app.config['FILE_UPLOADS'], uploaded_file.filename)
            uploaded_file.save(filepath)
            with open(filepath) as file:
                csv_file = csv.reader(file)
                for row in csv_file:
                    data.append(row)
            data = pd.DataFrame(data)
            print(data)
            return render_template('index.html', tables=[data.to_html(classes='data')], titles=data.columns.values, header=False, index=False)
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)


@app.route('/help')
def help():
    return render_template('help.html')

app.config['FILE_UPLOADS'] = "C:\\Users\\Zachary\\Documents\\VSCode_Projects\\monday_webapp\\app\\static\\file\\uploads"
```

This is a sample CSV I'm using

```
"Month", "Average"
"May",  0.1
"Jun",  0.5
"Jul",  0.7
"Aug",  2.3
"Sep",  3.5
"Oct",  2.0
"Nov",  0.5
"Dec",  0.0
```

Comment: What is 'X' and 'Y' in your example?

Comment: Honestly that's really what's confusing me, I was told to make a program that takes a CSV as an input and than plots the X and Y values. I'm assuming in this the month name would be the x and the other values would be the y, I'm supposed to be making them into a single, and multiple line graph, a bar graph and a stacked bar graph

Comment: what's your graph library?  chartjs? I use flask apps that I do AJAX requests using jQuery  then create chartjs graphs

Comment: I'll probably be using pyplot since I've worked with it before and since I'm running a python backend, I could use something like that but I planned to use pyplot when I went through the program in my head. Which do you think is the better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is by doing

```
d_list = list(data.columns.values)

        x_label = d_list[0]
        y_label = d_list[1]
```

This allows me to do plt.plot(data[x_label], data[y_label])
I'm essentially turning the column names into a list and pulling out the first and second string and applying that to my dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
x= df["month"]
y=df["average"]

plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: The problem with that is that's specific to this CSV file, it needs to apply in a general sense so that it works will any 2 column CSV file which is where I'm getting stuck. I tried using iloc but kept getting a keyerror